# sunspot search on a has many association

Tags: ruby-on-rails, sunspot

I don't get how I can make a search using sunspot to work on a has_many association. The user selects  skills from a select_tag field and the results return records that match the skill_ids.

Just for the record, when I press the search button I get this back:

```
SOLR Request (294.1ms)  [ path=select parameters={fq: ["type:User"], q: ["4"], fl: "* score", qf: "", defType: "edismax", start: 0, rows: 30} ]
```

The `q: ["4"]` mentions the number 4 which is the ID of the skill I searched for. I get no results when I was suppose to get something back. I do get all users back as results when I submit with no parameters.

What I have done and figured out so far can be found below. Any tips or help to the right direction is greatly appreciated.

(Please let me know if you need any other info and I will add it right away)

My structure is as follows:

**In Users model** (user.rb)

```
  has_many :user_skills, dependent: :destroy
  has_many :skills, through: :user_skills

  searchable do
    integer :skill_ids, :multiple => true do
      skills.map(&:id)
    end
  end
```

**In Skills model** (skill.rb)

```
  belongs_to :user
  has_many :user_skills
  has_many :users, through: :user_skills

  searchable do
    integer :id, :multiple => true
  end
```

DB schema:

```
t.string   "name"
t.string   "category"
t.string   "slug"
```

**In User_skills model** (user_skill.rb)

```
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :skill
```

DB schema:

```
t.integer "user_id"
t.integer "skill_id"
```

In my search controller I have the following code segment:

```
@search = Sunspot.search(User) do
  fulltext params[:s_skills]
end

@users = @search.results
```

params[:s_skills] are the skill_ids extracted from a select_tag:

```
<%= select_tag :s_skills, options_for_select(Skill.all.collect{|e| [e.name,e.id]}, skills), {:id => 'e2', :multiple => true, :placeholder => "Input skills", class: "input-search2" } %>
```

which takes skills's name and returns their ids.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not actually searching in the `skill_ids` field you have indexed.

You must add something like:

```
User.search do
   fulltext params[:free_text]   #<-- YOU DON'T NEED THIS, PROBABLY?
   with(:skill_ids, params[:s_skills]) if params[:s_skills]
end
```

Comment: thank you that helps, however it does show me records that match either of ids. For example if I search for Ruby and Java it shows me users that have either Ruby or Java as a skill when I want to see users that have both Ruby and Java in their skills. Is there a way to tweak this?

Comment: fixed. I just use the "all_of". Thanks a million